# Blank/black screen on galaxy S3 with Jell bean v4.1.1

Tags: android, surfaceview

On some screens in my game I am using surfaceView. It works fine on every other device and android version except one - Samsung galaxy s3 with jellybean update 4.1.1

On this device all the screens using surfaceView go blank and nothing shows up. But I know the game is running because I can hear the sound running. On one of the screens I have set the orientation of the activity as landscape and there it works fine whereas all the other screens having potrait orientation are turning blank on loading

Comment: You need to tell a little bit more about what you are doing. For instance, I encountered problems recently with AnimationDraw because I was starting the animation `onStart()`, where, on some devices, the animation is not ready yet. So: do you create the SurefaceView in Java or in XML? What properties have you set? What's contained within the SurfaceView? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to turn off fullscreen.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

It's a bug of jelly bean for certain devices with hardware overlays.